# assistance/guidance merging child with parent on expand/collapse functionality table

Tags: javascript, jquery

First off, here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khemikal/r5xm9act/101/)

I am trying to find a good way per my example to merge rows that are currently to the right under the parent. For example from my JSFiddle, when Group 3 expands the 10, 11, 12, 16, 3, 37, 56, and 9 rows will be UNDER Group 3 instead of to the right of it...however I want the subtotal to stay where it is (the 10, 11, 12, etc stuff can just be blank). I am looking for a way to do this where I can apply it to a much larger scenario if needed (multiple expand/collapse levels). Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

```
//expand collapse based on parent class which is column 1
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent').prepend('+');

  $('.parent').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf('-') != -1) {
      var str0 = $(this).text().replace(/-/g, '+');
      $(this).text(str0);
    } else {
      var str = $(this).text().replace(/\+/g, '-');
      $(this).text(str);
    }
    var $row = $(this).parent();
    var rowspan = +$(this).attr('rowspan') || 4;
    $.merge($row, $row.nextAll()).slice(0, rowspan).find('.child').toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: My first inclination would be use `<div>` as group (master) level container and put details data in table within a child. Subtotals also in `<div>` and position/size would be dependent on a toggled "open" class. More flexibility positioning and sizing <div> within each other than trying to deal with things like rowspan/colspan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery assistance - on click show child rows under parent instead of to the right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37598796/jquery-assistance-on-click-show-child-rows-under-parent-instead-of-to-the-righ)

Comment: In fact this is triplet by the same OP

Comment: apologies but my wording/explanation on those previous are off, ill delete those